# not able to read text field value provided as default value in a parameter Schema in C# TBB

Tags: 2013, content-manager, schema, c#, tbb

I created one Parameter Schema and added one text field `testText`, and assigned `9` as the default value for that field in schema. I have assigned this parameter schema to my TBB in CMS. Now i am trying to retrieve the value `9` in my C# TBB using below code

```
string validCount = package.GetValue("testText");
```

but i am not able to retrieve the field value what i have assigned as a default field value. It's returning me empty value.
For reference i used [this question](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/11250/how-to-pass-component-field-value-to-c-tbb-using-parameter-schema.)

While running the template in builder, if i am assigning the parameter value manually, code is working fine. But i need that default value what i have assigned to the field through code.
Kindly point me out if i am missing anything. I have found many questions on same topic and found same answer everywhere. but in my case i am unable to get the value using this approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that default values in Parameter Schemas actually work.

If you want default values for your TBB parameters, you should put those in your code (in case a Package item named after the parameter is not found).

Comment: Thank you @Rick for the suggestion, I found the same answer here https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/11419/default-value-of-parameter-schema-text-field-does-not-appear-in-template-builder , but it should be updated by SDL and if we could actually use that field then that would be a great relief. I will mark this is as answer as there is no proper solution to this issue when we are using Parameter Schema.

Comment: You can submit your idea here: https://community.sdl.com/ideas/sdl-tridion-dx-ideas/sdl-tridion-sites-ideas/i/sdl-tridion-sites-ideas